# Microsoft office 365 add-in + Azure Auth token graph

Tags: javascript, java, microsoft-graph-api, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have a problem getting token for Microsoft Graph.

I have followed [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins) to get the token.

With the Office Javascript API, I get from my add-in the identity token and the application token.

I have put my add-in on the exchange server, I have checked that an application was created in Azure Active Directory, add all authorizations for Microsoft Graph and Azure Active Directory for this application and generate a key for API access.

When I'm in Outlook, I open my add-in and I get the 2 token. In this step, i think the first step is done.

```
function getCallbackToken() {
  Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(cbToken);
}

function cbToken(asyncResult) {
  var token = asyncResult.value;
  console.log("token : " + token);
}

function getIdentityToken() {
  Office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync(cbIdentity);
}

function cbIdentity(asyncResult) {
  var identity = asyncResult.value;
  console.log("identity : " + identity);
}

function getMailUser() {
  console.log(
    "displayName : " +
      Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.displayName +
      ", mail adresse : " +
      Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress
  );
}
```

when I send theses token to my java server, I would like to get the token to Microsoft Graph, I request azure with `ADAL4J` library with this code

```
    //idToken , token identity or token application get from addin api javascript
    public AuthenticationResult acquireTokenForGraphApi(String idToken) 
    throws Throwable {
    final ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(" --- application id get in azure application list --- ",
            "  --- generate key from  azure application setting, only display one time ---");
    final UserAssertion assertion = new UserAssertion(idToken);

    AuthenticationResult result = null;
    ExecutorService service = null;
    try {
        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        String tenantId = "--- tocken get in azure configuration panel, application endpoints";

        final AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(
                "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId + "/", false, service);



        final Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken("https://graph.windows.net/", assertion, credential, null);


        result = future.get();

    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        throw e.getCause();
    } finally {
        if (service != null) {
            service.shutdown();
        }
    }

    if (result == null) {
        throw new ServiceUnavailableException(
                "unable to acquire on-behalf-of token for client " + aadAuthFilterProp.getClientId());
    }
    return result;
```

i get an error code

```
com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: { 
    "error_description":  "AADSTS50013: Assertion contains an invalid signature."
    [
        Reason - The key was not found., 
        Thumbprint of key used by client: '0600F9F674620737E73404E287C45A818CB7CEB8', 
        Configured keys: 
        [ 
            Key0:Start=02/18/2018, End=02/19/2020, Thumbprint=oZkMJ7Omv9GN7JVM;
            Key1:Start=03/31/2018, End=03/31/2020, Thumbprint=xq4mEGikJ5Bkblfw;
            Key2:Start=11/16/2016, End=11/16/2018, Thumbprint=i1DVz66b9dfpPV3Z;
        ]
    ]
    Trace ID: b439ed2f-8a91-401e-91e8-133b57532b00
    Correlation ID: cd8ebc72-5173-4725-9c79-e8dc0ef7634b
    Timestamp: 2018-04-10 08:27:05Z,
    "error": "invalid_grant" 
}
```

Comment: You actually need to call getAccessTokenAsync API to a get a SSO token for an office 365 user that you can exchange for a graph token. If the user is on on-prem you can fallback to taking the user through the oAuth flow and mapping to the exchange ID token. I recommend reading through the following docs:

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/authentication

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/implement-sso-in-outlook-add-in